# The mecahnism about how `overflow:hidden` on `body`element prohibits user from scrolling

Tags: css

I was making my blog,
and wanted to add functionality which prohibit user from scrolling while the modal is open.
So I found out that setting `overflow:hidden` on `body` element works for this.
But how?? I know the `overflow` property's default value is `visible`. It allows the contents to overflow out of the box.
but it seems that computed `body` element's height is stretched along with its contents and completely contains all of them in itself. and there was no overflowed contents.
[image]
Furthermore, the scroll bar position remains unchanged after closing modal.
[image]
[image]

So I wonder how the `overflow:hidden` works for this.

Comment: what's your body's height set at?

Comment: `hidden : 
Overflow content is clipped at the element's padding box. There are no scroll bars, and the clipped content is not visible (i.e., clipped content is hidden), but the content still exists. User agents do not add scroll bars and also do not allow users to view the content outside the clipped region by actions such as dragging on a touch screen or using the scroll wheel on a mouse. The content can be scrolled programmatically (for example, by setting the value of the scrollLeft property or the scrollTo() method), in which case. The element box is a scroll container.`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values

Comment: I set nothing body's height at all and nothing to inherit it just stretched along with its contents

Answer (score 0):

This prevents the scrolling functionality because the body tag encompasses all the page content not just the modal. So by making all (x & y) overflow hidden, the body copy that would have previously been scrollable is now hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement such a mechanism by using JavaScript to set the "overflow-y: hidden" on body when the menu is open and set it back to auto when it is closed. You should also set menu's overflow to scroll or auto. If I misunderstood your answer please provide some more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there is nothing to wrong in my understanding.
I simply overlooked the specific value of the `hidden` property within the `overflow` property.
There is nothing overflowed in `body` element.
I was just confused concept of 'overflowing' with the stretch due to the boxes in the `body` element.
Accroding to developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values , the `hidden` value simply takes the `scroll-bar` away  from the element.
That's all.